# how to implement hashmap

Tags: javascript, node.js

i use hashmap in order to store the key value pair of the map.Please suggest me if their is an alternative way to do the same using NOdejs.

```
var HashMap=require('hashmap');
var map=new HashMap();
map.set("amit",[1,2]);
map.set("amit",[3,4]);
console.log(map.get("amit"));
```

On console it print [3,4], i want [1,2,3,4].
How am i going to approach this.
if value in the value variable repeated then i also want to increase the count of the value corresponding to the same key.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `amit` keys value every time you call `set` on that key. Unless there is some specific API support in `hashmap`, your best bet is to concatenate the previous value on every `set` call.

Consider:

```
var HashMap = require("hashmap")

var map = new HashMap()
map.set('amit', [1,2])
// Concat previous value with [3, 4]
map.set('amit', map.get('amit').concat([3,4]))

console.log(map.get('amit'))
// [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You could also make an abstraction for this. The following is a simple example, you would most likely want to extend it further in a real use-case.

```
// concatSet('foo', [1, 2])
// concatSet('foo', [3, 4])
// console.log(map.get('foo')) => [1, 2, 3, 4]
function concatSet(key, value) {
   // empty array if not exists
   var prevValue = map.get(key) || []
   return map.set(key, prevValue.concat(value))
}
```

Comment: thank You.
one more question if once again somebody enter map.set("amit",[1,4,5]);
then is their a way to tell 1 enter two times.

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure I understand your question. My assumption is `[1, 4, 5]` should be `[1,1,4,5]`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop the map.

```
map.set(1, "test 1");
map.set(2, "test 2");
map.set(3, "test 3");

map.forEach(function(value, key) {
    console.log(key + " : " + value);
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashmap

Comment: my question is when key is same.